# Unable to get webcam image on Raspberry Pi (Arch Linux)

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, webcam-capture, archlinux-arm

I am using Raspberry pi (Arch Linux) to get webcam image with [webcam-capture](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) (0.3.9) library with Java (1.8.0_06), but my application fails with the following stack trace:

```
11:18:42.578 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.openimaj.OpenImajDriver
11:18:42.585 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.openimaj.OpenImajDriver not found
11:18:42.589 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.civil.LtiCivilDriver
11:18:42.595 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.civil.LtiCivilDriver not found
11:18:42.598 [main] INFO  c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Searching driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.jmf.JmfDriver
11:18:42.604 [main] DEBUG c.g.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDriverUtils - Driver com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.jmf.JmfDriver not found
11:18:42.607 [main] INFO  com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - Webcam driver has not been found, default one will be used!
11:18:42.659 [webcam-discovery-service] DEBUG c.g.s.w.d.b.WebcamDefaultDriver - Searching devices
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/BridJExtractedLibraries8835024590982118533/bridj.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
getLibrarySymbols has 141 symbols
11:18:46.381 [webcam-discovery-service] DEBUG c.g.s.w.d.b.WebcamDefaultDriver - Found device HP Webcam GJ502AA /dev/video0
11:18:46.439 [main] DEBUG com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - Setting new resolution 320x240
11:18:46.533 [atomic-processor] INFO  c.g.s.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask - Opening webcam HP Webcam GJ502AA /dev/video0
11:18:46.536 [atomic-processor] DEBUG c.g.s.w.d.b.WebcamDefaultDevice - Opening webcam device HP Webcam GJ502AA /dev/video0
11:18:46.540 [atomic-processor] DEBUG c.g.s.w.d.b.WebcamDefaultDevice - Webcam device /dev/video0 starting session, size java.awt.Dimension[width=320,height=240]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6e37204, pid=2297, tid=2901406816
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_06-b23) (build 1.8.0_06-b23)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.6-b23 mixed mode linux-arm )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x79204]  strcpy+0x14
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /root/Downloads/motion-capture/hs_err_pid2297.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted
```

http://pastebin.com/FB7Z1gvQ

The JVM heap log referred in the stack trace(/root/Downloads/motion-capture/hs_err_pid2297.log) above are here:

http://pastebin.com/pFNYRk81

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was not able to solve the problem with [webcam-capture](http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/) (0.3.9) library, I dumped it and used xuggler by using the sample code defined here:

https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DisplayWebcamVideo.java

To compile xuggler for raspberry-pi, follow:

[Guide to compile Xuggler for Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218879/guide-to-compile-xuggler-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using an HP webcam. Have you made sure to install the correct drivers for your cam? You can list your usb devices by typing the following command:

```
# lsusb -t
```

You can also check this link to see the list of device drivers installed on your pi and make sure if you can actually see the camera driver installed or not:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-list-of-modules-or-device-drivers-in-the-linux-kernel/

Comment: Well I can see my webcam via 'lsusb -t', moreover I am able to generate images using 'fswebcam' and 'ffmpeg' with my webcam, so driver issue is not the problem here.

Comment: What messages did you find in the following log file as mentioned in the stack trace? /root/Downloads/motion-capture/hs_err_pid2297.log

Comment: It's in the pastebin link already, edited my question for more clarity to refer the relevant info, please check it.